# Extra data is being inserted in my sqlite database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, malformed

Bad data is being inserted into my Search model sqlite database.  Instead of "string" the data is being entered as "---\n- ''\n- string\n" for one specific column (:city).  Also, the number '1' is being inserted automatically for the neighborhood_id.  UPDATE: I solved the string problem by deleting the city column and adding a city_id and a BTHM relationship.  Now the number '1' is being inserted for both the neighborhood_id and the city_id.  Here is the collection select code in the view:

```
<%= form_for @search do |f| %>
<li>Select City <%= f.collection_select(:city, City.order(:name), :name, :name, {:prompt => "Enter Cities"}, {:multiple => true})%></li>
<li>Select Neighborhood(s)<%= f.collection_select(:neighborhood_id, Neighborhood.order(:name), :id, :name, {:prompt => "Enter Chicago Neighborhood(s)"}, {:multiple => true}) %></li>
<li><%= f.submit 'Search' %> </br><%= link_to "Reset Search", root_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

The selection goes to a Search model that stores all of the search parameters.  Here is the schema for the City model:

```
create_table "cities", :force => true do |t|
    t.string    "name"
    t.timestamp "created_at"
    t.timestamp "updated_at"
  end
```

And the schema for the Search model:

```
create_table "searches", :force => true do |t|
    t.string    "city"
    t.integer   "beds"
    t.decimal   "baths"
    t.integer   "price"
    t.string    "name"
    t.timestamp "created_at"
    t.timestamp "updated_at"
    t.integer   "neighborhood_id"
  end
```

Here is the Search controller (thanks Yule for the suggestion):

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @searches = Search.all
  end

  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    @user = current_user unless current_user.nil?
    @search.save
    @listings = @search.listings
    if @listings.blank?
    else
      @listings = @listings.flatten
      @no_search_results = @listings.count
      @json = @listings[0,250].to_gmaps4rails do |listing, marker|
              marker.json "\"id\": #{listing.id}"
      end
    end
  end

  def new
    @search = Search.new
    @search.save  
    redirect_to @search
  end

  def create
    @search = Search.new(params[:search])
    @search.user_id = session[:user_id] unless session[:user_id].nil?
    @search.save
    redirect_to @search   
  end

  def destroy
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    @search.destroy    
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
     @search = Search.find(params[:id])
     @search.update_attributes(params[:search])
     redirect_to @search
  end
end
```

And here is the search model:

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :neighborhoods
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cities

  scope :named, where("name IS NOT NULL")  # for view: only show searches for user where user has saved a name.

  def listings
    @listings ||= find_listings
  end

  private

  def find_listings

    i = 0
    batch_size = 4000
    max_return = 150
    total_listings = 0
    db_size = Listing.count
    search_results =[]

    while total_listings < max_return && batch_size*i <= db_size do


      listings = Listing.order(:price).limit(batch_size).offset(i*batch_size).scoped

      if neighborhood_id.present?
        listings = listings.where(:neighborhood_id => neighborhood_id)
      end

      if city.present?
        listings = listings.where("city LIKE ?", city)
      end
    i = i + 1
         search_results << listings
         if search_results.present?
         total_listings = total_listings + search_results.flatten.count  
         else
         end

        end
        if search_results.present?
          listings = search_results.flatten[0..149]
        else
          return nil
        end
  end
end
```

In my development environment, when I select 'Algonquin' it gets inserted into the database like this:

```
=> #<Search id: 322, city: "---\n- ''\n- Algonquin\n",
```

Also, the neighborhood_id is always set to '1' even if a neighborhood is not selected at all!

Here is console output that shows the input parameters and how '1' is being saved for neighborhood_id and city_id.  In this scenario I selected 3 Bedrooms and city 'Algonquin' which now has city_id => 1148, and I did not select any neighborhood.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cS4xGLsBZJASlEmexmR2tUSMV+doBX30C14jHFRDqTA=", "search"=>{"city_id"=>["", "1148"], "neighborhood_id"=>[""], "max_distance"=>"", "m_max_distance"=>"", "beds"=>"3", "baths"=>"", "min_price"=>"", "price"=>"", "user_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Search"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "searches" ("baths", "beds", "city_id", "created_at",  "min_price", "neighborhood_id", "price", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["baths", nil], ["beds", 3], ["city_id", 1], ["created_at", Sat, 25 Feb 2012 08:15:04 CST -06:00], ["min_price", nil], ["neighborhood_id", 1], ["price", nil], ["updated_at", Sat, 25 Feb 2012 08:15:04 CST -06:00], ["user_id", nil]]
```

The City table is clean.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening, or some strategies to diagnose or fix the problem?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your controller code may be useful here

Comment: Can you post the code for your `Search` model?

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>Select City <%= f.select(:city, City.order(:name).collect(&:name), {:prompt => "Enter Cities"}, {:multiple => true})%></li>
```

Comment: This produces the exact same result.  Instead of "Algonquin" as the :city, the model shows "---\n- ''\n- ''\n- Algonquin\n"

Comment: there might be the case that city record itself contains value like `"---\n- ''\n- ''\n- Algonquin\n"`. Can you examine the data inside cities table

Comment: Yes I did, the city table is clean.  This syntax "---/n- '.... looks like the serialize syntax.  I removed the :city column, added a :city_id column and created a belongs to has_many relationship.  Problem solved....although I don't understand how the problem began in the first place!  I still have a problem where the number '1' gets inserted into both the neighborhood_id field AND now the city_id field even if nothing is selected!  Also, if I select other cities or neighborhoods, the results are still city_id => 1 and neighborhood_id => 1.  Very weird.